# check date in Create table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am setting a new table about borrowing books in PostgreSQL.
the book cannot be borrowed longer than 56 days
but I don't get a right table because my check date isn't right.
this is my Code:

```
Create table loaning(
    Signature varchar PRIMARY KEY ,
    loanDate date  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    returnDate date default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '28 day' 
        check((date loanDate + integer '56') < returnDate),

            );
```

Comment: If your table is about borrowing books, how do you plan for things out of your control, that is when people return the books later? https://edition.cnn.com/2018/10/05/us/overdue-library-book-returned-84-years-later/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting syntax like this:

```
create table loaning (
    Signature varchar PRIMARY KEY ,
    loanDate date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    returnDate date default CURRENT_DATE + interval '28 day' 
    check ((loanDate + interval '56 day') < returnDate),
);
```

You get the interval expression correct on `returnDate`, but not in the `check` constraint.  Also, there is no reason to convert a `date` to a `date`.

I would recommend that the primary key be a serial column, so I would really recommend something like this:

```
create table loaning (
    loaningId serial primary key,
    signature varchar(255),
    loanDate date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    returnDate date default CURRENT_DATE + interval '28 day' 
    check ((loanDate + interval '56 day') < returnDate),
);
```

I don't know what `signature` is.  But perhaps it is not even unique.